# Job queue – dealing with stuck records

Tags: 8, cron, queue

I have a cron job that gets stuck because I have a loop claiming items from the queue that ends on `numberOfItems() == 0`, which never happens because one of the queue items is stuck and cannot be claimed.

Clearly this is a flaw on my side, but I am trying to understand how to best address it. The `claimItem()` method returns `FALSE` every time in this case, so it should be easy to handle cases of bad queue processing, for example:

```
while ($item = $queue->claimItem()) {
    // process item
}
```

However, what if the first queue item is "faulty", while there are other queue items that are perfectly fine? I will never be able to retrieve them in this method. It also seems impossible to move on to the next item in the queue if `claimItem()` returns false (please correct me if I am wrong).

What is the correct way to handle such cases with Drupal's queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the code from the `claimItem` method it only returns FALSE if no items are available to claim.

So if `$queue->claimItem()` returns FALSE you can be sure that all available items are claimed (or failed to be claimed).

```
public function claimItem($lease_time = 30) {
  // Claim an item by updating its expire fields. If claim is not successful
  // another thread may have claimed the item in the meantime. Therefore loop
  // until an item is successfully claimed or we are reasonably sure there
  // are no unclaimed items left.
  while (TRUE) {
    try {
      $item = $this->connection->queryRange('SELECT data, created, item_id FROM {' . static::TABLE_NAME . '} q WHERE expire = 0 AND name = :name ORDER BY created, item_id ASC', 0, 1, [':name' => $this->name])->fetchObject();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
      $this->catchException($e);
      // If the table does not exist there are no items currently available to
      // claim.
      return FALSE;
    }
    if ($item) {
      // Try to update the item. Only one thread can succeed in UPDATEing the
      // same row. We cannot rely on REQUEST_TIME because items might be
      // claimed by a single consumer which runs longer than 1 second. If we
      // continue to use REQUEST_TIME instead of the current time(), we steal
      // time from the lease, and will tend to reset items before the lease
      // should really expire.
      $update = $this->connection->update(static::TABLE_NAME)
        ->fields([
          'expire' => time() + $lease_time,
        ])
        ->condition('item_id', $item->item_id)
        ->condition('expire', 0);
      // If there are affected rows, this update succeeded.
      if ($update->execute()) {
        $item->data = unserialize($item->data);
        return $item;
      }
    }
    else {
      // No items currently available to claim.
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```